# Create an axios instance with a default method?

Tags: axios

I'm trying to create an axios instance with `axios.create()` but can't seem to figure out how to set a default method on the instance.

**Is not working**

```
export default axios.create({
    request: {
        method: 'post'
    },
    baseURL: apiPath,
    responseType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

## A possible solution

- You can just pass your method into the config object like this `axios.create({ method: 'your-method' })` then you do `theReterunedInstance.request()` .

## Example

- This is a simple running example.
- I'm using a simple online REST API response from https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all

-

```
exampleMethod() {
    var instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: "https://dog.ceo/",

        method: 'get',

        //If you need to send a token to the service
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR-TOKEN-HERE'
        }

    });
    instance.interceptors.response.use(
        response => {
            console.log(response.data.message.terrier);
            return response;
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );
    instance.request("api/breeds/list/all");
}
```

## Live running example

- You can see it as a live running code https://codesandbox.io/s/mm8pw1jzwy

## Recommendation

- Please check the documentation of axios at https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios.